# Выдать ошибку при вводе буквы

Tags: c++

Строка состоит ТОЛЬКО из цифр. Следовательно, при вводе буквы необходимо выдать ошибку. Как это реализовать? (P.s строка типа char)

Comment: а что попробовали вы?

Comment: if (any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](char ch) { return (!isdigit(ch)); })) {
        cout << "Ошибка!\n";
    }

Comment: Но это получатся только со string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//headers
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    size_t const n = 100;
    char s[n];

    cin >> s;
    if (any_of(s, s + strlen(s), [](unsigned char ch) { return isalpha(ch); })) { 
        cout << "Error!\n"; 
    }
}
```